# In Jekyll, how to add links to pages in a subfolder?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll website where baseurl is "". On the homepage i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:4000/` I have a link to another page called `My Projects`. On this page, I'd like to add links to some of the HTML files which are stored under `_projects` folder in the base Jekyll directory.

I tried adding the following markdown to access the page.

`[My first Project]({{site.baseurl}}/_projects/file_1.html)`

which navigates to

> `http://127.0.0.1:4000/_projects/file_1.html`

as expected. But I get the 404 page not found error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you post your current `_config.yml` file? The way these files are processed depends on some of your settings in the setup file.

Answer (score 0):

If you store pages in **_projects** folder, you need to add it to you `include` array in **_config.yml**.

```
include:
  - _projects
```

This is because Jekyll ignores doted (eg : .gitignore) and underscored (eg : _projects) files and folders, except if you "*include*" them.